# Получить background-image div'а без повторной загрузки изображения

Tags: javascript, background-image

Если у контейнера стиль background-image: url , то можно ли средствами js получить это изображение, не загружая его повторно? сам url получить получается, но загружать снова по этому адресу - не вариант, картинка меняется.

Может есть ещё какие-нибудь возможности (устроило бы даже меню ПКМ, но у таких изображений нет пунктов, связанных с копирование и сохранением изображения).
Единственный пока вариант -заходить в консоль разработчика, в ресурсы и там находить это изображение руками и сохранять.

Ниже код для получения ссылки, если вдруг кому-нибудь пригодится.

```
function
 getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}


var div_element = getElementByXpath("//html/body/div..."),
    style = div_element.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(div_element, false),
    bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");
console.log(bi)
```

Answer (score -1):

Если вы хотите получить base64 изображение, то хотите ли вы того или нет, вам нужно сделать на него запрос.

```js
let imageURL = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/The_entrance_to_Carlton_Town_football_club_-_geograph.org.uk_-_793919.jpg'

fetch(imageURL).then(r => r.blob()).then(b => {
  let reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    console.log(reader.result)
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(b)
})
```

Comment: В том то и дело, нужна не ссылка, а само изображение, сохранить его или преобразовать в базе64.

Comment: @Николай исправил ответ, вам теперь подходит?

Comment: Кто то минус влепил. Это не я :) Нет, не подходит. Если бы просто нужно было скачать - вопроса не было. При повторном скачивании изображение скачается другое. В базе64 можно конвертнуть, разместив изображение в канвасе. Код тоже такой есть. Не понятно, как из стиля получить само изображение, а не ссылку на него.

Comment: @Николай Я знаю, у вас репутации недостаточно. Я только сейчас вопрос понял нормально... Из стиля никак нельзя получить изображение, т.к. по стандарту изображение хранится в формате ссылки (в виде текста в стилях) и потом подгружается браузером, в итоге вы можете только ссылку, но не само изображение.